# First 3 letters in caps and remaining letters in small case in a name -SQL

Tags: sql

i have  question, In a name (eg. Richard) first 3 letters should be in capital letter and remaining letters should be in lower case.

ANS: RIChard

can you help me to get the query for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own string handling functions.)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server has UPPER() and LOWER() functions that could change the characters to upper case and lower case.
for your demand, you need to use UPPER for your first 3 letters:
you can use the left() or substring functions to get the first 3 letters.
and for the remaining letters, you need to use the LOWER function.
for splitting the remaining letters you need to use the right or substring functions plus Len() function to calculate the remained letter counts.

```
Select  UPPER(Left(Name,3)) + LOWER(right(Name,len(Name)-3))
```

OR

```
Select  UPPER(substring(Name,1,3)) + LOWER(substring(Name,4,len(Name)))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Descriptions and DBMS have been added.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT('richard',3))+LOWER(SUBSTRING('richard',4,LEN(richard')));
```

Explanation: Upper() is to capitalize the letter, as you can see, I use it with LEFT(), Left() will get the 3 letters from the left, 3 means the number of character that you want. The substring() will extract the remaining letters, starting from the forth

Comment: Explanation: Upper() is to capitalize the letter, as you can see, I use it with LEFT(), Left() will get the 3 letters from the left, 3 means the number of character that you want. The substring() will extract the remaining letters, starting from the forth.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @learning an explanation is great, but it would be even better if you edited it into your answer

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following if you want to update it:

```
UPDATE employees SET First_name = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(First_name,3)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(First_name,4)))
```

You can test it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vuCbu4ViBevz6GF5gtpuJZ/0)

If you want to only have it in a select you can use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(First_name,3)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(First_name,4))) as First_name FROM employees;
```

You can test it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j71cfG8agFpPn1bvSoDG7d/0).

What I'm doing in both cases is the following:

1. Get the first 3 characters, and convert it to uppercase
2. Get all the other characters, and convert it to lowercase
3. Concatenate the two string together

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

// Try this:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT('richard',3))+LOWER(SUBSTRING('richard',4));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: no, the answer not getting

Comment: SELECT UPPER(LEFT(First_name,3))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(First_name,4)) from employees i tried like this aswell.

Comment: @SanalKumarKrishna Please test on the query I posted 37 minutes ago

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.